# How to see object/class/context browser in GNU Smalltalk?

Tags: browser, command, smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I run `get` and now I'm seeing blank screen. I expected object browser, but there isn't. I think there is some command for that.

How can I see those object/class/context browser in GNU Smalltalk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the REPL, there are a couple of tools to inspect code and objects. For instance:

```
anObject inspect
```

will show you the internals of anObject.

If you need to retrieve the code of a particular method, you can do:

```
(MyClass >> #myMethodSelector) methodSourceString
```

As for a browser... well, you're in a text-based REPL, there is no such thing as a code browser. Still, you can give gst-browser a try, it's a GUI for GNU-Smalltalk that includes a Browser, Transcript, Workspace, Debugger, Inspector, etc. Take in account it's still in beta though!

Cheers.